# Restrict IP addresses Google APIs and Accesing from GKE (Google Kubernetes Engine) Request Denied

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-kubernetes-engine, permission-denied

I created API Keys to enable **Geocoding API**, **Maps JavaScript** API and **Places API** with Restrict IP with **Cloud NAT IP**.
My API Keys access from Kubernetes on GCP (Google Kubernetes Engine/GKE), when im test curl get response request denied because response from from **IPV6 Address**.

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Wonogiri&types=&key=MY-API-KEY'
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key. Request received from IP address IPV6_ADDRESS, with empty referer",
   "predictions" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}
```

But im curl to ***ifconfig.me*** the response is IP Cloud NAT (34.87.xxx.xx).
Im very confused.

[image]
[image]